# Any there other pairs similar to "advise/advice" and "devise/device"?

Tags: spelling

I was wondering if there are other similar pairs for "advise/advice" and "devise/device"?

Updarte: I found this useful tip [here](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/blog/article/100/#:%7E:text=Licence%20is%20the%20noun%20and%20license%20is%20the%20verb.&text=(b)%20remember%20that%20%27ice,the%20end%20for%20the%20noun.)

> (b) remember that 'ice' is a noun and therefore the words with '-ice'
> at the end are also nouns. This works for the nouns 'advice' and
> 'practice', but with 'licence' you look for the shortened '-ce' at the
> end for the noun.

Comment: They are **not** homophones, at least in USA: *devise* is pronounced *devize* and *advise* as *advize*.

Comment: They're not homophones as @DrMoishe pointed out. They're [minimal pairs](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/minimal-pairs-s-z-final.php)

Comment: (At least in British English) there are "practise/practice" and "license/licence".

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for mentioning them. You can create an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many pairs like that, the ones I can come up with are:

- *use* (noun) and *use* (verb)
- *house* (noun) and *house* (verb)
- *close* (adj) and *close* (verb)
- *rice* (noun) and *rise* (verb)

[Nouns + adj → /s/, verb → /z/]

and,

- *mouth* (noun—with /θ/) and *mouth* (verb—with/ð/)
- *teeth* (noun) and *teethe* (verb)

Comment: *Use*, *house* and *close* changes pronunciation, they are **not** homophones.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: OP's examples aren't homophones either

Comment: yes, that was mentioned above, in the answer.